# What are the differences between classes, packages, namespaces, and modules?

Tags: programming-languages, terminology

I'm trying to decide what the most appropriate/generic terminology would be for referring to a file or group of files that defines an object that can be reused. The terms I hear most often are class, package, namespace, module, unit, and component but I'm unsure what the differences are or whether they are universally accepted terminology for different languages.

Comment: are you looking for links to wikipedia?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, those terms are used in many different technologies.

Namespaces and packages are a bit similar in the sense that they generally are "the relative path where the class is stored". Most of the time, a package or namespace will be the same as the path where the file is located (but the syntax might differ).

A class is a data structure, a unit of code that does something specific, logically. Breaking down your code in aptly named classes putting them in aptly named packages/namespaces helps a lot when comes time to find the code you are searching for just by looking at your project's structure and the files it contains. This "architectural concern" is one of the challenge of developing software that is easy to maintain.

Then, when your software becomes too big, you might want to break down your code into "modules". This basically means that instead of having one big project containing all the source code, you will "extract" all classes linked to a functionality (eg. if you have a search engine, you might want to isolate all the code for that in a different "module" which basically is another folder/project). This way, you could also reuse your search engine for another, completely different project, without having to copy (thus doubling) your code ... this would save a lot of maintenance work if you were to make a change in the search engine that you want in both projects.